# Creating a custom template format in Play 2.5

Tags: scala, model-view-controller, types, playframework, customization

I'm trying to make a custom template format (in ***Play 2.5_ & _Scala 2.11.11***) by following the [*Play documentation*](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCustomTemplateFormat) but I'm here so that means it's not working out for me.

I want the new template to have a file extension of "*stream*" (as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b1XLka0UIw) which is a few years old now) so I created this file as the documentation suggests:

```
   package ui

   import akka.NotUsed
   import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Source}
   import play.twirl.api._

   import scala.collection.immutable

   case class HtmlStream(source: Source[Html, NotUsed]) extends Appendable[HtmlStream] {

     def +=(other: HtmlStream): HtmlStream = andThen(other)
     def andThen(other: HtmlStream): HtmlStream = HtmlStream(source.merge(other.source))

   }

   object HtmlStream {

     def apply(text: String): HtmlStream = apply(Html(text))
     def apply(html: Html): HtmlStream = HtmlStream(Source.single(html))

   }

   object HtmlStreamFormat extends Format[HtmlStream] {

     def raw(text: String): HtmlStream = HtmlStream(text)
     def escape(text: String): HtmlStream = raw(HtmlFormat.escape(text).body)

     override def empty: HtmlStream = ???
     override def fill(elements: immutable.Seq[HtmlStream]): HtmlStream = ???

   }
```

And added this to the *build.sbt* file:

```
   TwirlKeys.templateFormats += ("stream" -> "ui.HtmlStreamFormat.instance")
```

I can't see where or how to include the following implicit (on the pre-mentioned *[Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCustomTemplateFormat)* - at the bottom); which might be the issue:

> Play can write an HTTP response body for any value of type A for which
>   it exists an implicit play.api.http.Writeable[A] value. So all you
>   need is to define such a value for your template result type. For
>   instance, here is how to define such a value for HTTP:

```
   implicit def writableHttp(implicit codec: Codec): Writeable[Http] =
  Writeable[Http](result => codec.encode(result.body), Some(ContentTypes.HTTP))
```

When I try to create a new `view` file, e.g. called `test.scala.stream` it doesn't recognise what type it should be so it seems something is definitely wrong. Help needed with this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have since cracked this one and in the spirit of community here it is.

1) Create a file (I called mine "*HtmlStream*" as I was looking to stream HTML):

```
   package ui

   import akka.NotUsed
   import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Source}
   import play.twirl.api._

   import scala.collection.immutable
   import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

   case class HtmlStream(source: Source[Html, NotUsed]) extends Appendable[HtmlStream] {

     def +=(other: HtmlStream): HtmlStream = andThen(other)
     def andThen(other: HtmlStream): HtmlStream = HtmlStream(source.merge(other.source))

   }

   object HtmlStream {

     def apply(text: String): HtmlStream = apply(Html(text))
     def apply(html: Html): HtmlStream = HtmlStream(Source.single(html))

   }

   object HtmlStreamFormat extends Format[HtmlStream] {

     def raw(text: String): HtmlStream = HtmlStream(text)
     def escape(text: String): HtmlStream = raw(HtmlFormat.escape(text).body)

     override def empty: HtmlStream = raw("")
     override def fill(elements: immutable.Seq[HtmlStream]): HtmlStream = elements.reduce((agg, curr) => agg.andThen(curr))

   }

   object HtmlStreamImplicits {

      implicit def toSource(stream: HtmlStream)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Source[Html, NotUsed] = {
      stream.source.filter(_.body.nonEmpty)

   }
```

2) I added these lines to the *build.sbt* file:

```
   TwirlKeys.templateFormats += ("stream" -> "ui.HtmlStreamFormat")
   TwirlKeys.templateImports ++= Vector("ui.HtmlStream", "ui.HtmlStream._", "ui.HtmlStreamFormat._", "ui.HtmlStreamImplicits._")
```

3) I added a template called test1.scala.stream (using a *file association* of HTML when prompted):

```
   @(body: HtmlStream)

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <title>title</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="assets/stylesheets/main.css">
          <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/favicon.png">
          <script src="assets/javascripts/hello.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <h1>Streaming the body</h1>

      <div>
          <div>
              @body
          </div>
      </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

4) Finally I could use this template as I would any other template by converting it into the new *HtmlStream* type.

```
  def streamHtml = Action { request =>

    val async1: Future[Result] = rr.getAsync(embed = true)(request) // get future
    val async1Html: Future[Html] = async1.flatMap(x => Pagelet.readBody(x)) // separate function to convert Future[Result] to Future[Html]
    val htmlStream: HtmlStream = HtmlStream(fromFuture(async1Html)) // c onvert to HtmlStream type

    Ok.chunked(views.stream.test1(htmlStream)) // chunk the new data type by sending through new template

  }
```

Hope this is helpful to someone else!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Custom Format that I code, following the play specifications,for cvs and works, including your question about ContentTypes.HTTP:

Some recommendations:

1-If you want that play framework can write an HTTP response body you need to define the body content. Look in the code below **implicit def contentTypeCsv** that is what you have to do BUT in your specific body content.

2-Other important advice, twirl templates with CUSTOM FORMAT should be defined in built.sbt where your custom templates are located, does not matter if the project is  single or multi project.

```
class Csv(buffer: immutable.Seq[Csv],text:String,escape:Boolean) extends BufferedContent[Csv](buffer, text) {

  val contentType = Csv.contentType

  def this(text: String) = this(Nil, Formats.safe(text),false)
  def this(buffer: immutable.Seq[Csv]) = this(buffer, "",false)


  override protected def buildString(builder: StringBuilder) {
    if (elements.nonEmpty) {
      elements.foreach { e =>
        e.buildString(builder)
      }
    } else if (escape) {
      // Using our own algorithm here because commons lang escaping wasn't designed for protecting against XSS, and there
      // don't seem to be any other good generic escaping tools out there.
      text.foreach {
        case '"' => builder.append("\"\"")
        case c => builder += c
      }
    } else {
      builder.append(text)
    }
  }
}


object Csv {
  val contentType = "text/csv"
  implicit def contentTypeCsv(implicit codec: Codec): ContentTypeOf[Csv] = ContentTypeOf[Csv](Some(Csv.contentType))

  def apply(text: String): Csv = new Csv(text)

  def empty: Csv = new Csv("")
}
object CsvFormat extends Format[Csv] {
  def raw(text: String): Csv = Csv(text)
  def escape(text: String): Csv = {
    new Csv(Nil, text, true)
  }

  def empty: Csv = new Csv("")

  def fill(elements: Seq[Csv]): Csv = new Csv(elements)
}
```